# Missing "iOS Local Devices" and "Android emulators" from the play dropdown

Tags: visual-studio, maui

VS 2022 Pro 17.4.3

I'm working on building my first cross platform .net Maui app on iOS and Android and grabbed a project off of github that demonstrates the functionality I want to use.  I loaded the solution and see that it's configured to compile through a remote Mac but it's missing the local iOS and Android emulator menu options under the play drop down menu.  I did verify that the hot restart is enabled in the tools-options-Xamarin-iOS Settings.  I also do have a paid developer account for Apple.

How is this menu option enabled?

I'm still trying to get my Mac to compile the iOS (I'm having cert issues between my PC and Mac but haven't exhausted my searches on this issue yet).  But in the meantime, I thought I could get up and running with the hot restart until I get the cert issue resolved.

Comment: You can refer to this case: [No IOS simulator or device appear on Visual Studio](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e3b2cea2-3d3d-4e21-b2e2-cc976c74aa92/no-ios-simulator-or-device-appear-on-visual-studio?forum=xamarinforms).

Answer (score 0):

The output type in the project may be set to library rather than Exe.

1. Right click the project, unload the project
2. right click the project, edit the project file
3. Change `<OutputType>` to "Exe"
4. Save Project File
5. Right click the project, load project.